# SQL Count number of true values from a row then multiply with another column

Tags: mysql, count, multiplication

I am trying to count the number of true values from a row, and so far it's looking good. After I get the value I would like to multiply that with the value from column 'Amount' in the same row.

Table *test* look like this, type of LA and MD are tinyint (checkbox)

```
ID   |  Amount |   LA   |   MD
------------------------------------
1    |    7    |   1    |   0
2    |    2    |   1    |   1
```

So far I can count true values from table *test* using:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM test
WHERE LA = true
```

But ones I start implementing the multiplication it gets messy, not yet that steady on the syntax. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And `SELECT Amount * LA FROM test` doesn't work?

Comment: What is the result that you want for this example?

Comment: (miltos) -I would like for row 1 to be 7 and row 2 to be 4.

Comment: (U2EF1) -SELECT Amount * LA FROM test just produces a row with the number of LA from each ID.

Comment: why `row2` to be 4? Is it `ID * Amount`?

Comment: It is because in row 2 I have 2 items (amount) that needs to run both the LA and MD analyze. So the total will be 4 analyzes. 

If I count analyzes (LA and MD) for row 2 I get 1+1=2, and multiplied with amount which is 2 I get 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the correct result if you have `LA=False` and `MD=True`, try

```
SELECT Amount * (LA + MD)
FROM test
WHERE LA = true
    OR MD = true
```

Comment: Just a follow up; How do I order this by name? (LA, MD..)

Comment: You don't have "name" column. If you mean LA and MD columns add at the end of query `ORDER BY LA, MD` and if you want to change the order to descending use `ORDER BY LA DESC, MD DESC`

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment, the query should be following

```
SELECT Amount * (LA + MD)
FROM test
```

Comment: Thank you, sarwar026! 

Both your answers are giving me what I need, and now I know how to tweek it to my needs, appreciate it!

Wanted to vote both of you, but that is not allowed since I have no reputation, so you're left only with my gratitude :)

Comment: I think, `where` clause is not necessary here. Anyway, thanks!